# How to write reusable component when sort of complexe dependency occurs

Tags: angular, typescript, design-patterns, components, interaction

I'm working on angular since few weeks now, and I was wondering how can I write clean component without too much dependency and big reusability.

I have to say that my issue is related with big architecture where things already exists.

Lets say I need to write a component that display a choice with 2 Radio button : either you can select "Playlist 1" or "Playlist 2".
This component have an Service called "PlayerService" that have a method called "Play" that take an array of Songs.
The idea is to select a "Playlist 1" or "Playlist 2" and on a button click, call the PlayerService with the correct Playlist.

Here is a basic implementation :
This code is for demonstration only.

**BasicComponent.ts**

```
import { PlayerService } from '../services/player.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-basic',
  templateUrl: './basic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./basic.component.css']
})
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit {

  private playlistArray = [
    { name: "playlist1", sounds: ["sound1.mp3", "sound2.mp3"]},
    { name: "playlist2", sounds: ["sound2.mp3", "sound3.mp3", "sound4.mp3"]}
  ]

  public SelectedPLayListName: string;

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onPlayButtonClicked(): void {
    var playList = this.playlistArray.find(x => x.name == this.SelectedPLayListName);

    this.playerService.Play(playList.sounds);
  }
}
```

**PlayerSercice.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayerService {

  constructor() {}

  public Play(sounds: any[]): void  {
    console.log("Start Play on a Playlist containing " + sounds.length + " elements");
  }
}
```

So as i mentioned above, we have the BasicComponent which have 2 playlist in an array, 2 radio button and a button to validate the choice.
On validation the component gives the correct array to the PlayerService.

**That's not the bahavior I would like / I can implement based on the current project achitecture.**

The BasicComponent can't have the PlayList array in his own class.
Instead I would like to being able to give him the playlist array from the parent component as an input for exemple.
This can be done easly, declaring an @Input, etc etc.

**That's still not the bahavior I would like / I can implement based on the current project achitecture.**

I dont want my BasicComponent to have the PlaylistArray as an @Input, I only want one playlist object.
The one that my user selected by clicking on my radio button INSIDE my BasicComponent.
So I would like my BasicComponent being able to display the choice between Playlist1 and Playlist2, then somehow ask for the correct playlist from his parent
and give this to the PlayerService

I came up with 2 way of doing this :

- **@Input / @Output :**

  - Getting a playList from the parent component by an @Input parameter.
  - Then on user click on the PlayButton, the BasicComponent "emit his @Ouput" called "OnPlay" with the name of the selected playlist as argument
  - The parent react to this @Output and retrieve the good playlist and set it as input for the BasicComponent
  - The BasicComponent implement a logic that detect change on the Input and if it change because we emited the output, then he can call the play method on the service with this playlist.

I thinks there is a lot of ugly code behing this, mostly because of this latency between the @output.emit, and the actual change of the @input.
This idea is not a really good one at all, but I thinked about it.

- **@Input a Service :**

  - Creating an interface IPlayListProvider that containt a method GetPlayList(name: string).
  - Creating a service PlayListProvider and Inherit from IPlayListProvider.
  - Creating an @Input in my    BasicComponent, of type IPlayListProvider.
  - So the parent can have (from DI in the constructor) and store an instance of the PlayListProvider.
  - So the Parent can pass this instance on the service as input to the BasicComponent.
  - The BasicComponent can now call the method GetPlayList with the SelectedPlayListName in the radio button choice when the user click on the PlayButton.

I like this implementation because this service isn't very coupled to my BasicComponent, I can reuse my component and provide an other service that also implement this interface and it will work.
I can keep all the thing where they should be even if I will need to do some logic so, the PlayListProvider service can retrieve the playlist whereever they are.
The Only things is, I dont know if its like Dangerous to do this, if it can break things in my Angular projects, if its against angular best practice.

Or maybe is there an other way ? (that keep things separated, and my component reusable)

What do you think ? How would you do this ?

**Edit 1 :**

*In my original post version, I didn't talk about my requirement :
In fact I actually have this kind of implementation to do within an existing code. The "Parent compoment" already exist and do not store any playlist but, he have services that can be used to retrieve a playlist by name.
By business requirement, I can't dirrectly use this service inside my components. I have to pass throught this parent component, I can modify the parent but not too much, not is structure or behavior.
So my component **need** to work as a "middleware" that provide choice, and ask for data to another service or component ans pass it to the Player. Morehover, this Input system need to be reusable, I should be able to take that component, and lets say, past it into a new project, and he needs to works here without any modification inside this component. 
Thats a lots of constraint but that's constraint that I can't break.*

Answer (score 2):

Good practice is that data management goes into a service, and template management goes into a component / directive / pipe ...

Second good practice is that Angular provides an `async` pipe that really eases the management of RxJS features such as observables and subjects.

Third good practice is that your angular features should have a single responsibility.

Fourth good practice is that you should reduce the change detection iterations. Thanks to the previous good practices, that can be easily done.

Now let's get to coding.

First your HTTP service

```
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http: Httpclient) {}

  getPlaylists() {
    return this.http.get('...');
  }
}
```

Now, your store/cache/data service :

```
export class StoreService {
  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
    this.refreshPlaylists();
  }

  playlists$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  refreshPlaylists() {
    this.httpService
      .getPlaylists()
      .subscribe(list => this.playlists$.next(list));
  }

  addPlaylist(playlist) {
    this.playlists$
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(list => this.playlists$.next([...list, playlist]));
  }
}
```

You also have your player service, which remains untouched.

Now, in your component :

```
export class BasicComponent {
  constructor(
    public data: StoreService,
    public playerService: PlayerService
  ) {}
}
```

And in its HTML :

```
<div class="playlist" 
  *ngFor="let playlist of playlists$ | async" 
  (click)="playerService.play(playlist)">

</div>
```

As you can see, the code et simplified, you can clearly see what each feature does, and everything is reusable without any headache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But here my problem is that even if my BasicComponent dont know how the service is implemented, he is still very coupled with him. I mean if tomorrow I need to extract that component to use it in another part of the software that have an other service that provide playlissts i will have to modify this component to use the other service

Comment: @NicolasPretot that will always be an issue, you can't go against that. From that, there are 2 solutions : either aggregate everything in the same module (because modules should be re-used, not components or services), or create an interface that will be implemented by any service that interacts with your component (similar to `OnInit`, your service would implement that interface, so that the new service will have to comply with it too)

Comment: I was afraid to hear that.In fact that was my first thought but i tried. Thanks anyway for all this information, I might found a way with a promise to accomplish this but. I will try to see if changing the architecure will be possible. Thanks for all this infos

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer following a smart / dumb component idea.

The main component, music-player component can be the smart component, it handles all logic and uses services as it requires. The smart component also makes use of dumb components for display and events.

`music-player` can have

1. A playlist-service that gets a list of playlists. It can also have a method to provide a list of songs provided a playlist id.
2. A playlist component that displays a list of playlists provided as @Input and displays its info and encapsulates the style. It also implements a selection logic whenever a playlist is selected.
3. A songs component that displays a list of songs provided a song list as @Input, it also emits an event when a song is selected.
4. A button for Play that is enabled when a playlist is selected.

---

<kbd>music-player.html</kbd>

```
    <playlist [items]="playlists" (playListSelected)="loadSongs($event)"></playlist>
    <songs [items]="songs" (songSelected)="playSong($event)"></songs>
    <button type="button" (click)="playSongs()">Play</button>
```

Here music-player is the smart component that uses different services to get/set data using services. It also uses different dumb components to display content and capture user actions.

**To answer your original design question**, `@Input` / `@Output` goes well in the communication between Smart / Dumb components. Services goes well in the communication between a smart component and outer environment.

In my experience testing is also easy with this approach.

Don't take this for a final design, I am just trying to do an intro to the concept of smart / dumb components. There are a lot of articles out there that you can search for.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I would say I like that design. Unfortunately in my scenario have to create this component, in an existing software, with minimal changes. This component needs to be able to get the playlist as input and offer a choice, then pass it to a existing player service. Thanks for your answer